# What is the word used in this line of this song for which I've typed up these lyrics?

Tags: lyrics, religious-music

I've recently rediscovered an artist named Saint of Sin. They have religious sounding music, most of which appear to be non-verbal as per their Spotify page. There are a few songs with lyrics, including this one - [Saint of Sin - Welcome to Saint of Sin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XNsmCSaXpv8). I've gained a few new favourite tracks from them, including this one.

I searched and couldn't find lyrics for it, so I typed them up. My question is, what is the 2nd or 3rd word of the 5th last line? I cannot make it out and I'm curious to know what it is. The line in question from below is is: "Climb to life? tonight? lie?". I think it is "Climb to life", but I'm not sure.

Saint of Sin - Welcome to Saint of Sin

2019

Welcome to Saint of Sin
Nothing ever stands still
The passage of motions sway and sweep
Swirling up billows of starlight
Bursting into the void of blackness
Reminding us of an echo of the ancient call
The sound is distant
But the forbidden skies open up
Like a celestial eye
Beckoning to a voyage of a different kind
A thunderous welcome turns into an icy hush
And we drift into the silence standing tall
In a vessel of gold on waves of anticipation
The fireworks of solar flares shed their translucent rays
To reveal the sacred kingdom
Once believed to be lost forever behind the clouds
Gabriel shows us a passageway that seems to have no beginning and no end
A perfect circle of eternity, an infinity
Nothing shall be lost
The higher we go the more we see
The more we feel with each breath
Rise, ascend!
The ancient call will have no end
**Climb to life? tonight? lie?**

A birthplace with no end
Go back, go back!
Return to love again
(Return to love again)

Answer (score 1):

I hear "Climb to life." There is a clear "f", though slightly detached from the rest of the word. It also makes since given the prior lyrics about rising and the following lyric about birth.